# Разбить массив по узким условиям и составить массив массивов, поиск лучшего решения

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Всем здравствуйте и добрый день.

Сегодня столкнулся с интересной задачей и хочу поделиться со знатоками, в поиске наиболее интересного варианта.

Задача следующая:

> Получаем массив объектов с двумя ключами, время и значение. Необходимо составить из него многомерный массив, где массив второго уровня будет собран исходя из того, что время между индексами не больше чем N.

У меня вышел гомункул, время исполнения которого не составляет более ~0.07

Пример кода ниже, а вопрос собственно в следующем, не горжусь изящностью своего варианта, но хотелось бы увидеть мысли и решения других...

```js
const data = [
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:42:04+03:00', 'id': 73},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:38:04+03:00', 'id': 86},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:45:04+03:00', 'id': 43},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:39:24+03:00', 'id': 92},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:37:04+03:00', 'id': 70},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:46:04+03:00', 'id': 123},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:36:53+03:00', 'id': 43},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:43:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T16:43:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T16:44:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T16:45:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T16:46:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T22:46:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T22:47:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T22:48:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T22:49:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T22:50:04+03:00', 'id': 64},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:40:04+03:00', 'id': 93},
 {'time': '2017-10-18T12:44:04+03:00', 'id': 63}
];

console.time('time');
data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.time).getTime() < new Date(b.time).getTime() ? -1 : 1)

let sortedArrays = []
while (true) {
   let arr = []
   arr.push(data[0])
   if (!data.length) {
  break
   } else {
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const firstI = arr[0].time.slice(11, 13) * 60 + +arr[0].time.slice(14, 16)
    let nextI = data[i].time.slice(11, 13) * 60 + +data[i].time.slice(14, 16)
    if (firstI + i === nextI) {
   arr.push(data[i])
    } else {
   break
    }
  }
  data.splice(0, arr.length)
  sortedArrays.push(arr)
   }
}
console.timeEnd('time');
console.log(sortedArrays);
```

Comment: _время исполнения которого не составляет более ~0.07_ - для каких данных? как замерял? Как задается N? Ты уверен, что твой код решает задачу, которая была поставлена?

Comment: Бросается в глаза постоянный парсинг значений. Зачем?

Comment: Задачу решает на момент реализации. Далее идет специфическая отрисовка данных на графиках. Замер делаю `console.time` или `setTimeout`

Comment: Парсинг каких данных? Делал сравнения на основании времени конкретного объекта, последовательно вырезая те, которые уже были отобраны

Comment: Строкового представления времени

Answer (score 1):

> но хотелось бы увидеть мысли и решения других...

Не берусь сказать какие отличия есть по скорости выполнения от кода автора (по крайней мере, console.time показывает одинаковый порядок времени выполнения).

Алгоритм следующий:

1. на основе исходного массива строится новый с добавлением в каждый
   элемент поля, содержащего время записи в unix time
2. массив сортируется по полю времени unix
3. из отсортированного массива формируется новый массив в который
   последовательно добавляются массивы, содержащие записи, интервалы
   времени между которыми не превышают интервал N

последний массив является конечным и выводится

```js
const data = [
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:42:04+03:00", id: 73 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:38:04+03:00", id: 86 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:45:04+03:00", id: 43 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:39:24+03:00", id: 92 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:37:04+03:00", id: 70 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:46:04+03:00", id: 123 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:36:53+03:00", id: 43 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:43:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T16:43:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T16:44:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T16:45:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T16:46:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T22:46:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T22:47:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T22:48:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T22:49:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T22:50:04+03:00", id: 64 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:40:04+03:00", id: 93 },
 { time: "2017-10-18T12:44:04+03:00", id: 63 },
];

console.time("time");

const N = 100000;
let last = -9999999999999;
const mdata = data
 .map(e => {
  return { time: e.time, utime: Date.parse(e.time), id: e.id };
 })
 .sort((a, b) => a.utime - b.utime)
 .reduce((p, c) => {
  if (c.utime - last > N) {
   p.push([]);
  }
  p[p.length - 1].push({
   time: c.time,
   id: c.id,
  });
  last = c.utime;
  return p;
 }, []);

console.timeEnd("time");

console.log(mdata);
```

Comment: в чем отличие от того, что в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy отличия по скорости, алгоритму, коду?

Comment: с чего ты взял, что есть отличия по скорости? есть какие-то тесты? Алгоритм неизвестно отличается или нет, код по другому форматирован, ну да, есть немного. Стоит добавить описание в ответ, как работает предложенный код и чем он _лучше_ чем код в вопросе